# Pattern matching for product of two terms fails if one factor is 1

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have a long set of replacement rules that I utilize to solve some longish integrals over trigonometric functions. Just look at this snippet (from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67595/21606)):

```
validQ[coeff___, arg_, v_] := 
  FreeQ[{coeff}, v] && Exponent[arg, v] == 1;
testInt[v_, a_, b_] := {
   coeff___*Cos[arg_] /; validQ[coeff, arg, v] :> coeff/Coefficient[arg, v]*Simplify[(First@Differences[Sin[arg] /. {{v -> a}, {v -> b}}]), Trig -> False],
   (*failure rule*)
   integrand_ :> Inactive[Integrate][integrand, {v, a, b}]
   };
```

See, that e.g. `2*Cos[t] /. testInt[t, 0, \[Pi]/2]` returns `2` as expected. However, I am struggling with terms that are like `Cos[t]`:

```
Cos[t] /. testInt[t, 0, \[Pi]/2]
(* Inactive[Integrate][Cos[t], {t, 0, \[Pi]/2}] *)
```

Same for `1*Cos[t]`. However, applying the rules to `1.*Cos[t]` yields `2.`. In principle, I could just define an additional rule for `Cos` with the negative side-effect that I would have to be very cautious since this would also replace the `Cos` in terms where it may be wrong. How can I change the patterns so that ideally `coeff___*Cos` also accepts `1` as a coefficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that I was just able to answer my own question. I came across [Optional](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) which seems to do exactly what I want. Changing the rule according to

```
validQ[coeff___, arg_, v_] := FreeQ[{coeff}, v]  && Exponent[arg, v] == 1;
testInt[v_, a_, b_] := {
   (coeff___ : 1)*Cos[arg_] /; validQ[coeff, arg, v] :> coeff/Coefficient[arg, v]*Simplify[(First@Differences[Sin[arg] /. {{v -> a}, {v -> b}}]), Trig -> False],
   (*failure rule*)
   integrand_ :> Inactive[Integrate][integrand, {v, a, b}]
   };
```

does the job. By this, it is possible to provide a default value (here `1`) if `coeff` is absent in the expression. To test the rules:

```
Cos[t] /. testInt[t, a, b]
(* -Sin[a] + Sin[b] *)
2*Cos[t] /. testInt[t, a, b]
(* 2 (-Sin[a] + Sin[b]) *)
t*Cos[t] /. testInt[t, a, b]
(* Inactive[Integrate][t Cos[t], {t, a, b}] *)
```

**Update**

As pointed out by @Karsten in a comment, it is also possible to use `coeff_.` instead of `coeff___:1`.

Comment: Using `coeff_.` [should do the trick, too](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html).

Comment: @Karsten7. True, also works! Thanks for this.

Comment: You are using the syntax for a custom default value, but as you specify it to be the built-in default value for multiplication you might as well use that.